# Getting Sum of Related Table Column including Zero for No Results

Tags: laravel

I believe I have seen this something like this somewhere before but can't seem to locate anything this time around.

In my Laravel application, I have a table called `charge_types`. If a user wants to see a summary of charge types in relation to another model, I would like them to be able to see a column for each of the selected charges types against rows of the selected model. That's the easy part. The hard part is trying to SUM the total payment details for invoices with charge_types, even when there is nothing for a particular charge_type.

For example

```
Docket #     Application Fee     Renewal Fee     Discharge Fee
1            1.00                0.00            0.00
2            5.00                0.00            0.00
4            0.00                10.00           0.00
7            0.00                0.00            20.00
```

So far I have this working as filtering out the dates and the charges types I need, but I am not sure where to go for the SUMs I need to calculate.

```
 DB::table('dockets')
            ->join('invoices', 'dockets.id', '=', 'invoices.invoiceable_id')
            ->join('payment_details', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payment_details.payable_id')
            ->join('payments', 'payment_details.payment_id', '=', 'payments.id')
            ->where('payments.received_at', '>=', '2021-06-01')
            ->whereIn('invoices.charge_type_id', [$fees->pluck('id')])
            ->select('dockets.docket_number', 'dockets.last_name', 'dockets.first_name', 'payments.*')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also ran into the problem and i found nothing on internet.

But later i realized that we are rendering the data in the fronted which means you are looping the data to render it.

So you can easily sum up the charges while its rendering on the fronted.

```
just use one variable on the fronted which sums up each time you render a column and stores it.
```

Also you can easily do this by aggregate function

```
Auth::user()->Application->sum('fee');
```